# Facebook Application Development: Are there Tutorials, Screencasts, etc. that are Architecture Centric

Tags: php, facebook

Are there any good tutorials that outline proven Architecture patterns for Facebooks applications?  Most of the resources I've found in their development documentation are hello world oriented.  I'm looking for something (article, book, screencast, etc) that outlines common things that a Facebook application will do, and common, proven , repeatable ways of accomplishing that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This slides were pretty useful for me http://www.slideshare.net/folke/netlog-what-we-learned-about-scalability-high-availability-430211